# How can I neutralize the odours of certain washing detergents?

Tags: cleaning, clothing, smell, laundry, chemicals

Brands of clothes washing detergents such as **Tide**, **Gain**, and **Downey** contain a strong chemical odour which is offensive to me. No amount of airing-out will diminish this odour. Things washed using these detergents pass-on the odour when it comes into contact with other materials and clothes. Rewashing multiple times in non-scented detergents has not been effective.

**Is there anything I can do to save (stink neutralize) the contaminated things, short of throwing them away?**

Comment: The perfume will break down on its own so simply waiting will work. In the meantime switch to some other detergent. There's even a version of Tide devoid of scents and dyes.

Comment: Use a different detergent.

Comment: For the record, I do NOT use tide. The odor transferred to my garments. It's been over two years that the garments have been hung to air out. No other soap, or detergent has removed the Tide odor so far. It also transferred to containers that held the stuff. It's air cancer

Comment: Two years was enough time for the skunk smell in my jeans to break down after I got sprayed, so I don't think you're smelling the Tide detergent anymore.

Comment: @Ross Ridge. If I agreed with you, we'd both be wrong. Think whatever you like. Your olfactory might have diminished ability. There is no Tide™ detergent manufactured without added "scents."

Comment: Given the fact nothing you've tried worked, including any of the suggestions here and given that it's been three years now since your clothes have been exposed to Tide, I'm only more convinced what you're smelling isn't Tide. If you don't believe that simple and more rational explanation then it looks like you're pretty much out of options. All that's left to try now is to throw out all your clothes and everything else you think has become contaminated. Unfortunately, I doubt this would work. You're still going to end up smelling "Tide" on your new clothes as well.

Comment: Not that it really matters, but here's the version of Tide that's devoid of added scents and dyes: http://tide.com/en-us/shop/type/liquid/tide-free-and-gentle-liquid

Comment: @MrPhooky - Do people seek you out for your sage advice?

Comment: @Stan Pretty much my good friend, pretty much.

Comment: @MrPhooky - : ) God help them.

Comment: This may cause colors to fade a bit, but just rinse with very hot water, thoroughly until any soap residue is gone, and then leave the clothes outside for days or weeks. It is easy if you have a backyard or a balcony. Sprinkling/spraying a tiny bit of baking soda, vinegar, or enzyme cleaner may help speed it up, too, one at a time. Each chemical might only help break down part of the smell.

Comment: @RossRidge I, too, can attest that the chemical scents persist for years, after numerous washings.  I still can smell it in clothes that were laundered with the worst concoction some 10 years later, after multiple intervening washings.  For folks with sensitive senses of smell, the chemicals are debilitating.

Answer (score 4):

Wash the items again, with your normal soap, plus [half a cup of baking soda](http://www.rd.com/home/cleaning-organizing/8-ways-to-boost-laundry-detergent/). It would help to use the soaking cycle on the washing machine too, and lemon juice and vinegar can't hurt. If it's not enough, run another cycle with baking soda. I use baking soda on teenagers' sweaty socks and undershirts and jiu-jitsu uniforms, and they come out smelling perfectly. I believe in this power of baking soda so much that when I once bought a used book several hundred pages long smelling just as you describe, I spent a couple of hours spreading baking soda over every surface of every page, since of course you can't wash a book, then left it for a few days, then brushed off every surface of every page. It didn't turn out perfectly, since it wasn't washed, but close, and I can now use the book without any distraction of smell. By the way, *washing* soda is not as effective at removing smells in the laundry.

Comment: Nothing you suggest has worked at all. There is no change after AGGRESSIVE treatment.

Comment: your answer should be remove because it's off topic: you are talking about  smells caused by bacteria (which are easy to get rid off) the question is about synthetic chemicals produced to smell for a long time, like parfum. (And it's based on belief not on science `I believe in this power of baking soda so much that...`).

Answer (score 2):

I am in the very same boat so I understand completely.  The only thing I have found to help is a product called OdorKlenz.  I purchased mine on Amazon.  For clothing which retains some odor (perfume or other detergent smells) you can add it to the washer as directed.

For items which are heavily laden with the Tide or Cheer scents, that will not be enough.  I utilize a large muck bucket and soak the article in this product with enough water to cover.  I have MCS (Multiple Chemical Sensitivities).  I don a pair of rubber gloves and swish the clothing to make certain the product is pushed through them.

It may soak for one-three days, depending on the strength of the fragrance you detect.  Then I transfer the clothing to the washer and use this product as it recommends in the machine.  You may have to repeat this process, but you will notice a substantial reduction in the fragrance of the clothing.

Good luck, there are millions of us who are in the same shoes as yourself.

[http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00289VGJU?keywords=odor%20klenz&qid=1445389805&ref_=sr_1_1&sr=8-1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00289VGJU)

Comment: OdorKlenz seems to work well with almost every nasty natural smell from mildew to "fermented" gym towels and socks. The reviews specifically mention that it has little or no effect on detergent odors added to stink "fresh." I can't figure out how my things became so contaminated by a few hours of contact with things washed in that… "stuff."

Answer (score 2):

I've tried everything and I find soaking clothes in warm water and Calgon Water Softener (found it at Walmart near the oxyclean) for about a day works  well to get detergent smell out of used clothing.  Sometimes I'll add a little dish soap too if they are really strong. Then I rinse them well and wash with my regular laundry soap.  Seems to release the smells without adding another one, the light Calgon smell rinses away.  It's a little gross to see how much stinky detergent/fabric softener "film" rises to the top of the soaking water.  I think the Calgon removes the binding agents or hard water minerals that hold onto the fragrance and the dish soap de-greases the fabric softener.

Comment: I have read this comment several times, I'm trying it now. I will return and report

Comment: I saw a film appear and little particles rise to the top of my plastic bin within 1 hour. I washed and dried the clothes. The smell has greatly diminished but not disappeared. I'm going to repeat this process again and see what happens.

Comment: After getting my clothes back from my laundry service I've used for a year straight, the new provider decided to wash all of our clothes with so much scented detergent that the plastic bags they came back in were lined with a film of soap/detergent. This method saved my entire wardrobe!

Answer (score 1):

I have recently read that you can soak the garments afflicted with the stench in water with some **Vitamin C powder** mixed in. If you don't have any powder you can pop open a couple of the caplets and pour the contents into the water.

You could actually put the Vitamin C powder in with your washing detergent and that should be able to aid in reducing the smell.

Once you have finished washing, if possible, always allow the clothes to dry out in the sunshine - it is amazing what a bit of Sunlight can do to help!

Comment: I have obtained pure vitamin C powder AND a liquid form and treated the contaminated materials without any success.

Comment: I have tried the Vitamin C trick after trying with vineager rinse unsuccessfully and it seems to remove the scent pretty well, I used 4 orange scented tabs in 50 l of hot water (50+ degC) for one hour, then cold rinse in machine and tumble dry. Seems to have removed 85% of odors . However, I would recommend more tabs (10) and thorougly soak the garnments for more than one hour  in addition to soaking them both outside and inside out.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try Vinegar and/or lemon juice (With nothing mixed in it).

About a tablespoon of vinegar and a teaspoon of lemon juice usually work like magic against smells, but remember to rinse thoroughly before leaving it to dry.

Also, drying in the sunshine can help a lot.

Comment: Any comments on why the downvote...? Or is it just flaming wars?

Comment: I didn't downvote you. However, Nothing you have suggested has worked.

Answer (score 0):

Add 1/2 cup of household ammonia to your front load washer and add the stinky articles. Wash without adding any other detergent or softener. This should do the trick. I hate the smell of Tide, febreeze, and Downy! (I think the birds that fly above our homes do, too.) Despite what commercials say, something is only clean when it DOESNT have a scent!

Comment: ammonia smells bad, too. And it is not good for the rubber and plastic parts of the washing machine

Comment: Thank you. This has not worked. I agree that smelling from a chemical odour is not a smell of clean. It is the smell of chemical contamination. What the manufacturers are doing is criminal.

Answer (score 0):

Others, including some on cloth diaper boards, recommend a product called 'RLR', which is mostly sodium carbonate (washing soda),  which is also available as a pool cleaner—rinse very, very, thoroughly afterward.

Comment: I normally use washing soda rather than detergents. This was one of the first cleaners I tried… several times. I've even used it between other things. Washing soda is a well-known and long-time cleaning staple. Beware, though, the NEW Arm & Hammer™ Washing Soda stinks more than the Tide™ stench I was trying to neutralize. I tossed the whole box, unused, into the haz-mat box at the local dump. AVOID than stuff too.

Answer (score 0):

It can take 10 washings or more with white vinegar, baking soda, and an unscented detergent to get the Tide-like smell out of resale clothes.

In some cases, I've had to give up and redonate the clothing.