# Get rid of laundry detergent smell in room

Tags: smell

my parents used diluted laundry detergent to wipe the walls when they moved into an old apartment.
now the place is filled with laundry detergent smell, which is quite unpleasant
they tried to wipe the wall with cloth damped with water, but the smell is still intense
is there anyway to get rid of the smell?

Comment: Hi Peter C, Welcome to Lifehacks. A similar question has been asked previously: https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/6312/how-can-i-neutralize-the-odours-of-certain-washing-detergents and another similar question here: https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/22503/how-to-get-detergent-odor-out-of-wool-blanket

Answer (score 1):

Going from the easiest, most expedient way to remove the detergent odour to the most effective but expensive and labour intensive:

First, try to cover and encapsulate the wall surface using "Febreze Free" which is unique from other Febreze Fabric Refresher varieties because it contains no perfumes. All Febreze Fabric Refresher products are formulated to trap and neutralize bad-odour molecules in fabrics rather than simply masking them like some other product. Other scented products will add their odour to the existing one making the situation worse. You may need two applications — Allow plenty of time for the coating to dry between applications.

Second: Depending on the brand name (Tide, Gain, Arm and Hammer, etc.) and if the stuff was put onto wallpaper and has not soaked through to the drywall, You may be able to strip the wallpaper off the wall to remove the odour.

Third: If the odour has penetrated the drywall, try to use an ozone generator to minimize the odour. You may be able to rent one for your deodorizing. Ozone has it's own problems as it is hazardous to breathe. You may have to isolate the room while it undergoes treatment. You'll have to do your research. There might also be a professional deodorizing service available.

If that doesn't work, You've no choice but to gut the room tearing out the drywall for renovation.

I've been through this with family members that have multiple chemical sensitivity.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Wash the wall with vinegar first option.  Second if the smell is still there boil water in the room you figure out how .. I have used a kettle it does not work well... I bought a induction stove top single burner so I now use this.  Boil water in a pot of the induction if you have one add 2 table spoons of coffee... let it boil... vinegar can be used too.
Vinegar can be used with so so results in a kettle if the room is small like a bathroom that has offensive soap smells like shampoo ect.
I avoid all products that you can buy for such problems as I have found they generally add more chemicals I will have to deal with later.
More problems for me... washing with baking soda water and letting it sit for a time then rinsing with vinegar and water may work but will likely work.